# Problems with EDSL related implementation of array subscription in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dsl, type-families, type-level-computation, data-kinds

## Context

I'm trying to implement a EDSL that loosely resembles IBM's OLP (modelling language for linear programming).

## Code

#### Haskell EDSL Code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

-- Numbers at the type level
data Peano = Zero | Successor Peano

-- Counting Vector Type. Type information contains current length
data Vector peanoNum someType where
    Nil :: Vector Zero someType
    (:+) :: someType 
            -> Vector num someType 
            -> Vector (Successor num) someType
infixr 5 :+ 

-- Generate Num-th nested types
-- For example: Iterate (S (S Z)) [] Double => [[Double]]
type family Iterate peanoNum constructor someType where
    Iterate Zero cons typ = typ
    Iterate (Successor pn) cons typ = 
        cons (Iterate pn cons typ)

-- DSL spec

data Statement =
      DecisionVector [Double]
    | Minimize Statement
    | Iteration `Sum` Expression
    | Forall Iteration Statement
    | Statement :| Statement
    | Constraints Statement
infixl 8 `Sum`
infixl 3 :|

data Iteration =
      String `In` [Double]
    | String `Ins` [String]

data Expression where
    EString :: String -> Expression
    EFloat :: Double -> Expression
    (:?) :: Vector n Expression -> Iterate (n) [] Double -> Expression
    (:*) :: Expression -> Expression -> Expression
    Lt :: Expression -> Expression -> Expression
    Gt :: Expression -> Expression -> Expression
    Id :: String -> Expression
infixr 5 `Lt`
infixr 5 `Gt`
infixr 6 :*
infixr 7 :?

test :: Statement
test = 
    let rawMaterial = 205
        products = ["light", "medium", "heavy"]
        demand = [59, 12, 13]
        processes = [1, 2] 
        production = [[12,16], [1,7], [4,2]]
        consumption = [25, 30]
        -- foo = (EId "p" :+ EId "f" :+ Nil) `Subscript` production
        -- bar = (EId "p" :+ Nil) `Subscript` cost
        run = []
        cost = [300, 400]
    in  
        DecisionVector run :|
        Minimize 
            (Sum ("p" `In` processes) 
                 ((Id "p" :+ Nil) :? cost :*
                  (Id "p" :+ Nil) :? run)) :|
        Constraints 
            (Sum ("p" `In` processes)
                 ((Id "p" :+ Nil) :? consumption :*
                  (Id "p" :+ Nil) :? run `Lt` EFloat rawMaterial) :|
             Forall ("q" `Ins` products)
                    (Sum ("p" `In` processes)
                         ((Id "q" :+ Id "p" :+ Nil) :? production :*
                          (Id "p" :+ Nil) :? run `Gt` 
                          (Id "q" :+ Nil) :? demand)))

instance Show Statement where
    show (DecisionVector v) = show v
    show (Minimize s) = "(Minimize " ++ show s ++ ")"
    show (i `Sum` e) = "(" ++ show i ++ " `Sum` " ++ show e ++ ")"
    show (Forall i e) = "(Forall " ++ show i ++ show e ++ ")"
    show (sa :| sb) = "(" ++ show sa ++ show sb ++ ")"
    show (Constraints s) = "(Constraints " ++ show s  ++ ")"

instance Show Iteration where
    show (str `In` d) = "(" ++ show str ++ " `In` " ++ show d ++ ")"
    show (str `Ins` d) = "(" ++ show str ++ " `Ins` " ++ show d ++ ")"

instance Show Expression where
    show (EString s) = "(EString " ++ show s ++ ")"
    show (EFloat f) = "(EFloat " ++ show f ++ ")"
    show (Lt ea eb) = "(" ++ show ea ++ " `Lt` " ++ show eb ++ ")"
    show (Gt ea eb) = "(" ++ show ea ++ " `Gt` " ++ show eb ++ ")"
    show (ea :* eb) = "(" ++ show ea ++ " :* " ++ show eb ++ ")"
    show (Id s) = "(Id " ++ show s ++ ")"
    show (vec :? dbl) = "(" ++ show vec ++ " :? " ++ "dbl" ++ ")"

instance Show (Vector p Expression) where
    show (Nil) = "Nil"
    show (e :+ v) = "(" ++ show e ++ " :+ " ++ show v ++ ")"

-- eval_opl :: Statement -> [Double]
```

#### EDSL to OPL comparison

```
    let rawMaterial = 205
        products = ["light", "medium", "heavy"]
        demand = [59, 12, 13]
        processes = [1, 2] 
        production = [[12,16], [1,7], [4,2]]
        consumption = [25, 30]
        -- foo = (EId "p" :+ EId "f" :+ Nil) `Subscript` production
        -- bar = (EId "p" :+ Nil) `Subscript` cost
        run = []
        cost = [300, 400]
    in  
        DecisionVector run :|
        Minimize 
            (Sum ("p" `In` processes) 
                 ((Id "p" :+ Nil) :? cost :*
                  (Id "p" :+ Nil) :? run)) :|
        Constraints 
            (Sum ("p" `In` processes)
                 ((Id "p" :+ Nil) :? consumption :*
                  (Id "p" :+ Nil) :? run `Lt` EFloat rawMaterial) :|
             Forall ("q" `Ins` products)
                    (Sum ("p" `In` processes)
                         ((Id "q" :+ Id "p" :+ Nil) :? production :*
                          (Id "p" :+ Nil) :? run `Gt` 
                          (Id "q" :+ Nil) :? demand)))
```

corresponds to the opl code

```
float rawMaterial                     = 205;
{string} products                     = {"light","medium","heavy"};
float demand[products]                = [59,12,13];
{string} processes                    = {"1","2"};
float production[products][processes] = [[12,16],[1,7],[4,2]];
float consumption[processes]          = [25,30];
float cost[processes]                 = [300,400];

dvar float+ run[processes];

minimize sum (p in processes) cost[p] * run[p];

constraints {
  sum (p in processes) consumption[p] * run[p] <= rawMaterial;
  forall (q in products)
    sum (p in processes) production[q][p] * run[p] >= demand[q];
}
```

#### Relevant sections

```
(:?) :: Vector n Expression -> Iterate (n) [] Double -> Expression
```

as well as

```
instance Show Expression where
    [...]
    show (vec :? dbl) = "(" ++ show vec ++ " :? " ++ "dbl" ++ ")"
```

## Problem description

OPL uses brackets for array subscription and I tried to map subscriptions
to my EDSL using the following notation

```
((Id "p" :+ Id "f" :+ Nil) :? consumption
```

which corresponds to OPL in the following sense:

```
consumption[p][f]
```

in the former, (Id "p" :+ Id "f" :+ Nil) constructs a value of type Vector that contains type level information regarding the length of said vector. 
According to the definition of the constructor :?, you can see that,
Iterate (n) [] Double thus will expand to [[Double]]. 
This neatly works as expected. However, in turn to use the generated syntax tree, I need to pattern match against the actual values.

```
show (vec :? dbl) = "(" ++ show vec ++ " :? " ++ "dbl" ++ ")"
```

*Problem*: The above line works but I don't know how to *use* the actual data. How do I pattern match? Is it even possible to use the data anyway?
Replacement of dbl through the obvious

```
(Iterate (Successor (Successor Zero)) [] Double)
```

doesn't work. I also tried to build up a data family but I could not figure out a way to recursively create a family of all arbitrarily nested Lists of Double:

```
Double
[Double]
[[Double]]
[[[Double]]]
...
```

Comment: "I don't know how to use the actual data" — use in what way? Your question is cluttered with redundant details, but doesn't contain a clear explanation of what you actually want. Does [this](http://ideone.com/yw0148) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to know what value is actually stored by `Iterate n [] Double`, you must know some information about `n`. This information is typically given by the indices of some GADT, which correspond to the inductive structure of the index itself (commonly known as a [singleton](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons)).

But fortunately for you, you have already stored the `Nat` index in the structure of the `Vector`. You already have all the information you need at hand, you just need to pattern match! e.g.

```
instance Show Expression where
    ...
    show (vec :? dbl) = "(" ++ show vec ++ go vec dbl ++ ")" where 
      go :: Vector n x -> Iterate n [] Double -> String 
      go Nil a = show a 
      go (_ :+ n) a = "[" ++ intercalate "," (map (go n) a) ++ "]"
```

Note that in the first pattern, the type of `Nil` gives you `n ~ 0` which in turn gives you `Iterate 0 [] Double ~ Double` (simply by definition). In the second pattern, you have `n ~ k + 1` for some `k` and `Iterate n [] Double ~ [ Iterate k [] Double ]`. Pattern matching on the `Nat` allows you to view the inductive structure of the type family, essentially.

Every function you write on `Iterate` will look like

```
foo :: forall n . Vector n () -> Iterate n F X -> Y  -- for some X,Y
```

because you must have such a value-level proof in order to write any inductive function on `Iterate`. If you do not like carrying around these "dummy" values, you can make them implicit with a class:

```
class KnownNat n where 
  isNat :: Vector n () 

instance KnownNat 'Z where isNat = Nil 
instance KnownNat n => KnownNat ('S n) where isNat = () :+ isNat
```

but in this case, since your AST already contains a concrete `Vector`, you do not need to do any extra work to access the actual value of the index - just pattern match on the vector.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for. I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, all of them amount to encoding the depth of iteration at the value level so that you can pattern match on it.

#### GADT

The simplest way to do this is to make a GADT for representing iteration of the application of a type constructor:

```
data IterateF peanoNum f a where
    ZeroF      :: a                   -> IterateF Zero           f a
    SuccessorF :: f (IterateF pn f a) -> IterateF (Successor pn) f a

instance Functor f => Functor (IterateF peanoNum f) where
    fmap f (ZeroF a)       = ZeroF $ f a
    fmap f (SuccessorF xs) = SuccessorF $ fmap (fmap f) xs

-- There's also an Applicative instance, see Data.Functor.Compose
```

#### Singleton

If you're tied to your type family, you can use a singleton instead. A singleton is a type inhabited by a single value that you can pattern match on to introduce to the compiler facts known about that type. The following is a singleton for the natural numbers:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

data SPeano pn where
    SZero :: SPeano Zero
    SSuccessor :: Singleton (SPeano pn) => SPeano pn -> SPeano (Successor pn)

class Singleton a where
    singleton :: a

instance Singleton (SPeano Zero) where
    singleton = SZero

instance Singleton (SPeano s) => Singleton (SPeano (Successor s)) where
    singleton = SSuccessor singleton
```

A simpler `SPeano` singleton without the `Singleton` type class is equivalent, but this version doesn't require writing as many proofs, instead it captures them in the construction of the successor.

If we modify the `IterateF` GADT from the previous section to capture the same proofs (because I'm lazy) we can convert to the GADT whenever we have an `SPeano` singleton. No matter what, we can easily convert from the GADT.

```
data IterateF peanoNum f a where
    ZeroF      ::                          a                   -> IterateF Zero           f a
    SuccessorF :: Singleton (SPeano pn) => f (IterateF pn f a) -> IterateF (Successor pn) f a

toIterateF :: Functor f => SPeano pn -> Iterate pn f a -> IterateF pn f a
toIterateF SZero a = ZeroF a
toIterateF (SSuccessor pn) xs = SuccessorF $ fmap (toIterateF pn) xs

getIterateF :: Functor f => IterateF pn f a -> Iterate pn f a
getIterateF (ZeroF a) = a
getIterateF (SuccessorF xs) = fmap getIterateF xs
```

Now we can easily make an alternative representation for `IterateF` that's a singleton and an application of the `Iterate` type family.

```
data Iterated pn f a = Iterated (SPeano pn) (Iterate pn f a)
```

I'm lazy, and don't like writing proofs that could be handled for me by a GADT, so I'll just keep the `IterateF` `GADT` around and write functions for `Iterated` in terms of it.

```
toIterated :: Functor f => IterateF pn f a -> Iterated pn f a
toIterated xs@(ZeroF      _) = Iterated singleton (getIterateF xs)
toIterated xs@(SuccessorF _) = Iterated singleton (getIterateF xs)

fromIterated :: Functor f => Iterated pn f a -> IterateF pn f a
fromIterated (Iterated pn xs) = toIterateF pn xs

instance Functor f => Functor (Iterated pn f) where
    fmap f = toIterated . fmap f . fromIterated
```

The pattern matching in `toIterated` is to introduce the proofs captured in the construction of `SuccessorF`. If we had something more complicated to do, we might want to capture this in a [`Dict`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.6/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t:Dict)

#### Use any other encoding

In the specific case of

```
(:?) :: Vector n Expression -> Iterate (n) [] Double -> Expression
```

you have a `Vector n` that is encoding the depth of iteration of the `Iterate n []` at the value level. You can pattern match on the vector, which is either `Nil` or `(_ :+ xs)` to prove that the `Iterate n []` is either `Double` or a list. You can use this for simple cases, such as [`show`ing the nested values](http://ideone.com/yw0148), or you can convert the `Vector n` into another singleton to use one of the more powerful representations from the previous sections.

```
-- The only proof we need to write by hand
ssuccessor :: SPeano pn -> (SPeano (Successor pn))
ssuccessor pred =
    case pred of
        SZero        -> SSuccessor pred
        SSuccessor _ -> SSuccessor pred

lengthSPeano :: Vector pn st -> SPeano pn
lengthSPeano Nil = SZero
lengthSPeano (_ :+ xs) = ssuccessor (lengthSPeano xs)
```

Comment: But that does not solve my problem. Now I'd have to write something like SuccessorF (Successor F (ZeroF 32))  for [[32]] in my EDLS, which is totally unacceptable.

Comment: "all of them amount to encoding the depth of iteration at the value level" - it is already encoded in the `Vector` datatype. You do not need to define any additional machinery to do so.